# Using command prompt changing last extensions of a file

Tags: cmd

I want to change the last file name of an item using windows command prompt.

An example would be:
Filename is file.epub and replace it with file.zip

I tried doing:

> file.epub ren file.zip

I am not sure if I did this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `file.epub` to `file.zip`

Comment: I would have been surprised if it didn't. You are meant to accept it by the way.